# 2D array Of All Cyclic Shifts Of A 1D array

Tags: numpy, scipy, vectorization

Suppose `a` is some 1d `numppy.array` with *n* elements:

```
a = np.array([a_0, a_1, ..., a_n_minus_1])
```

I'd like to generate the 2d (*n X n*) `numpy.array` containing, at row *i*, the *i*th cyclic shift of `a`:

```
np.array([[a_0, a_1, ..., a_n_minus_1], [a_n_minus_1, a_0, a_1, ...], ...]])
```

preferably without loops. How can this be done efficiently?

(The function [`np.roll`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) seems related, but apparently takes only a scalar `shift`.)

Comment: The trick to doing this efficiently is to use diagonals. For example, the main diagonal will be all the first element, etc.

Comment: @JoeKington Way cool, thanks! IIUC, you mean to utilize the fact that a cyclic shift can be thought of as a linear transformation, yeah?

Comment: @JoeKington Actually, it sounds very good, but I can't figure it out - generating the matrices performing the different linear transformations would be very costly, no?

Comment: Basically, yes.  `np.diagflat` is the function you'll want, but unfortunately it doesn't take an `out` parameter to do the operation in-place.  Therefore, if you want to be _really_ efficient, you'll need to jump through a few other hoops.  I'm writing up an answer now, but it will take a bit. Someone will probably beat me to it :)

Comment: @JoeKington OK, many thanks for the enlightening comments! Unfortunately, still too many hoops for me to figure out how to jump through :-)

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Many thanks!

Comment: See also http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_circulant.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are actually building a circulant matrix. Just use the [scipy `circulant` function](http://scipy.linalg.circulant). Be careful, because you must pass in the first vertical column, not first row:

```
from scipy.linalg import circulant
circulant([1,4,3,2]
> array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
         [4, 1, 2, 3],
         [3, 4, 1, 2],
         [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

For reference, circulant matrices have very very nice [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by hand just use `np.tile`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Replicate it with tile but one more time than actually needed to get the wanted "shift"

```
b = np.tile(a, a.size+1)
# [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
```

Then reshape it so it is a 2D matrix with shape `(a, a+1)`

```
b.reshape(a.size, a.size+1)
#[[1 2 3 1]
# [2 3 1 2]
# [3 1 2 3]]
```

Ok, that was just a debugging step to see what is happening. But if you see it, you know you just have to delete the last column:

```
b.reshape(a.size, a.size+1)[:,:-1]
```

And then you have your wanted result.

---

This can also be generalized to allow (almost) arbitary shifts:

```
shift = 3
a = np.array([...])
b = np.tile(a, a.size+shift)
res = b.reshape(a.size, a.size+shift)[:,:-shift]
```